# Implementing WPS client in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2, wps, wpsclient

Is it possible (and what is the recommended way) to use OpenLayers 3 to do the work of the`OpenLayers.WPSClient`?

As shown in [the old WPS client example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/wps-client.html), OpenLayers 2 can be used to operate WPS.

There are OpenLayers 3 [examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/) for using other web services like WFS and WMS, but not WPS (as of 3.2.1).

Is this temporary or by design?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As part of the WPS-GUI project that I did I created a WPS client "library" that closely models after the OpenLayers 2 interface. It uses JSONIX for the all OGC XML marshalling and unmarshalling.

You can check it out here:

https://github.com/boundlessgeo/wps-gui/blob/master/src/wpsclient.js

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Is this js file stand-alone? This is a bit overwhelming for my js skills. There seems to be references in `wpsclient.js` to `HTML` elements and `"global"` variables. Could you please give a minimal example use, e.g. to call `gs:AddCoverages` or another wps in GeoServer/OpenGeo?

Comment: Have you looked at the OpenLayers 2 WPS example? The interface used here is very similar.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I started with OpenLayers 3, and need to test OpenLayers 2.

Comment: @bartvde Can you give me example of buffer using wps service in openlayer 3.??

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use the wps client from openlayers 2 in your openlayers 3 project. The response from the wps request is in WKT and you can easily format this to a openlayers 3 feature with the built in formatter.

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.format.WKT.html

(The response depending on what wps request you are using of course..)

I did this in a project as I did not have time to implement my own wps client.

Answer (score 3):

I also reused the openlayers 2 client in a [wps builder](https://github.com/openearth/wpsbuilder). I did have to [implement](https://github.com/SiggyF/openlayers/commits/fedor-wps) the `DefaultValue` and `ExecuteResponse` objects.

There is some wider need for a mapping client independent wps client, as seen in this [discussion](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/What-I-want-from-ows-js-td5158148.html) on working towards a ows.js (based on jsonix, like @bartvde's implementation). Since that discussion work has [started](https://github.com/OSGeo/ows.js). The WPS implementation has not started yet. The idea of javascript [ows.js](https://github.com/OSGeo/ows.js) is modelled after the convenient [owslib](https://github.com/geopython/OWSLib) library.

The main challenges in implementing a WPS client are:

- defining the xml to object mapping. That's the role of [jsonix](http://www.jsonix.org/) and the OpenLayers (2) [format readers](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format/WPSExecute-js.html).
- defining a convenient api for executing requests. If you look at the [owslib wps](https://github.com/geopython/OWSLib/blob/master/owslib/wps.py) implementation as an example you'll see that implementing a convenient api for the WPS processes is not a trivial task. The wide variety of options (with/without status, raw response/reference response, etc...) make supporting all possible in- and outputs quite a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a trick like this. Geoserver has a WPS Builder that can generate Xml Request from inputs and outputs. Then you can take the generated xml and pass it in a string variable in javascript. Replace xml input values with variables. In my case I needed only one process, but you can do a switch function.
You can use a simple xmlPost request to pass the xml string to geoserver.