# Geoserver: how to call a Geotools function from Openlayers

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers

I intend to create a custom Geotools function that does some special insertions into a PostGIS DB.

My question is how to call that function from Openlayers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest (only?) way to do this would be to create a [WPS function](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/process.html), [add that to GeoServer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implementing.html) and then [call it from OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136512/implementing-wps-client-in-openlayers-3).

Comment: Ian, is it ok to make it a WPS function, although this is not the task of WPS? it's something like a custom WFTS function.

Comment: I'm not sure if a function would be callable via a WFS-T you'd have to try, could call WPS to make the change and then WFS to post change

Comment: Can one create a custom WFS-T function? e.g. WFS:CustomInsert

Comment: Maybe you could ask another question which is about why you want to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Just a stab in the dark but...
create an application stack that has geoserver and a programming language container application that uses geo json, a java script library and the like and use that to call and put to the hosted layer.
The problem is your question is too broad and indicates you need to do some homemwork, as you don't grasp the complexity of the task you are undertaking.
Then someone giving a line of script would be easy.
A lyer is only the visual representation and not the coding that is needed on the backend application.
Look up LAMP AMP stacks.